# PHP change variable value in only one of multiple instances of a class

Tags: php, instance

I'm building a framework. I have a problem loading in multiple controllers, because they extend a base controller, where the instances are changed to the last loaded controllers options. How can i affect only the extended base controller of the controller class, that I'm currently working in, instead of affecting all instances of the base controller?

```
class loader
{
    private static $_inst;

    public function __construct($class) 
    {
        self::$_inst = $class;
    }
}

abstract class base_controller 
{
    protected $load;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->load = new loader($this);
    }
}

class controller1 extends base_controller {}

class controller2 extends base_controller {}
```

When the first controller loads, it sets the instance in the loader. But when you load the second controller, it sets controller1's loader objects static $_inst to controller2's instance. Suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to dereference a null pointer at line 525.

Comment: Do you use static properties in your base class?

Answer (score 1):

`$_inst` will stay the same in all classes because you have defined it as `static`

**Solution:**

Just remove `static` and make it `private $_inst;`

Comment: The problem is, that if I remove static, it will make a recursion (loop), but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Static members are shared at the level of its declaration class. If you want an other comportment, you have to declare it in every children classes.